# ffmpeg raw video over udp

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, ffmpeg

I am trying to stream desktop with as little latency as possible I am using this command to stream

```
ffmpeg -sn -f avfoundation -i '1' -r 10 -vf scale=1920x1080 -tune zerolatency -f rawvideo udp://224.3.0.11:5000
```

and for client side this command

```
ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format uyvy422 -framerate 10 -video_size 1920x1080 -fs -i udp://224.3.0.11:5000
```

The issue I am having is shown in this [screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnEoO.jpg) here from the client side does anyone know what I can do to stop this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Because of UDP.

UDP is an unordered protocol. Hence the video decoder did not receive the video packets in the correct order - causing the glitch in your video stream.